# How to tell EF Core to use entities from a different Context/Schema instead of creating the tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have two DBContext "A" and "B".

The following conditions apply:

1. "A" knowns "B" by project Reference.
2. "A" uses entities from "B" Context (Schema) as navigation/reference properties.

Outcome: EF Core creates B's tables in A instead of just using it.

How to tell EF Core that B's tables are in a different db schema  instead of creating them?

Any chance to configure this behavior With AddDbContext options?

Comment: Are you navigating from EntityA, which is managed by ContextA, to EntityB, which is managed by ContextB, using a navigation property?

Comment: I would like to use context B entities as navigation properties. Currently I mapped these properties as NotMapped, but the tables were created in context A anyways.

Comment: I can't imagine how EF Core is going to do that. EntityA maps TableA in database A. You use your navigation property to navigate to EntityB which maps TableB in (a different) database B in a LINQ expression. Which SQL statement should EF Core produce?

Comment: @Michael good question. I thought of importing a foreign database table behind then scene. But my main question is, how can I avoid automtica creation of tables of a different kontext and et me do the loading process of that foreign entity.

Comment: You can use `modelBuilder.Ignore<EntityB>();` in your OnModelCreating method, if EntityB is a DbSet of this context. If you are using SQL Server, and your databases are on the same server, you can create a view in database b which references to a table in database a. Then you can define this views as a view in EF Core with `modelBuilder.Entity<EntityA>().HasNoKey();`.

Comment: It is the same DB Server. Using NotMapped on the navigation property does not prevent EF from creating the table in context A. Is using NotMapped on the navigation property in any way different than using fluent api Ignore?

Comment: You can define a DbSet for the referenced entity, and then Ignore() prevents EF Core from creating this table. But it doesn't solve your problem because your navigations would be ignored in the resulting SQL statement. EF Core is a huge SQL generator. If there is no executable SQL statement for database A, which retrieves the requested data, EF core cannot do this job.

Comment: I would to the loading mechanism by myself. In this case I would store only the Id to the referenced entity and implement a lazy load mechanism using the IServiceProvider to inject an instance of DbContext "B". But my question was: What are the differences in marking the navigation property with NotMapped attribute and ignoring the type itself via mb.Ignore?

Comment: "Which SQL statement should EF Core produce?"
The same as you do when using tables from deifferent schemas. Unsure if EF Core does support using different schemas.